# Visual Studio Update 4

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, sdk, windows-phone-8.1

I was using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and writing a Windows Phone 8.1 App.
I updated my Visual Studio to Update 4 and restarted the computer.
Now all of my Projects are saying :

> One or more projects require a framework SDK
> (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1) that either is not installed or is
> included as partof future update to visual studio
>
> **This project requires visual studio update to load.**

It opens : [Download Site Of Visual Studio](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=12.0&sbp=TargetPackMissing&plcid=0x409&o1=WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)

New Projects can be created with no problems at all but, once i close visual studio, the same project cannot open again. Same error

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me (even though I was already running Visual Studio 2013 Update 4). I just followed the instructions from the download site.

1. Select Install now:

[image]

2. Download Visual Studio 2013 Update 4:

[image]

This downloaded a file VS2013.4.exe which I then installed and was then able to open Windows Phone 8.1 projects. I have no idea why they wouldn't open prior to installing the update package as I was already supposedly running update 4.